# Find the doubling time given the logistic growth formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm reading through [this chapter](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/6-7-exponential-and-logarithmic-models) of an online algebra textbook, currently I'm on exercise 19:

Given the logarithmic growth formula $\dfrac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}$ find the doubling time of a population. The solution provided is
$\space\sim 1.4\space$ however I get a nonsensical answer of $-1.155$.

To arrive at this I tried to use a function described earlier in this chapter, the doubling time function: $t=\dfrac{\ln2}{k}$ where I took $k$ to be the growth constant so I substituted from the log growth function provided:

$\text{doubling time} = \dfrac{\ln2}{-0.6} = -1.155$.

How  can I arrive at the correct solution $1.4$? Prefer any approach covered in this chapter to help reinforce what I've just read - the method must be in this page linked above somewhere but I cannot see it?

Comment: The intended solution is far more simple-minded: For what time $t$ does $f(t)=2f(0)$? (This approach can also be used for exponential growth.)

Comment: WolframAlpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cdfrac%7B1000%7D%7B1%2B9e%5E%7B-0.6t%7D%7D%3D2) offers a negative answer of $t\approx -6.6923$