# Find the doubling time given logistic growth $\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Given log growth function of $\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}$, find the doubling time.

My approach, with help from a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4023103/find-the-doubling-time-given-the-logistic-growth-formula).

First find the amount when time t = 0:
$f(0)=\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}=\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6*0}}=\frac{1000}{1+9e}$.

Using a calculator, $\frac{1000}{1+9e}=39.27$

So, $2f(0) = 2*39.27 = 78.54$

Now find the time t corresponding to this doubling amount from time 0:

$$78.54=\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}$$

(I'm unsure how to break down and simplify this formula from here on...)

Tried multiplying out the denominator:

$$1000=(78.54)(1+9e^{-0.6t})$$

Then isolate the term with the exponent:

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1000}{78.54} &= 1+9e^{-0.6t} \\
\frac{1000}{78.54}-1 &= 9e^{-0.6t} \\
\frac{(\frac{1000}{78.54}-1)}{9} &= e^{-0.6t}
\end{split}$$

This is starting to 'feel' wrong.

$$\ln(\frac{1000}{78.54}-1)-\ln(9)=-0.6t$$

I want to get $t$ on it's own, so divide everything by -0.6:

$$\frac{\ln(\frac{1000}{78.54}-1)-\ln(9)}{-0.6}=t$$

The solution provided by my textbook is 1.4. Running the above line through a calculator I get -0.44.

[image]

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at the correct solution 1.4?

Comment: $e^0=1$  and not $e$ : this is where you made the mistake.

Comment: +1, thanks for taking the time to articulate your reasoning, makes it much easier to find where the mistake is :)

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici! This did allow me to get to the correct solution